# How to fix Property 'on' does not exist on S3 data after upgrading the AWS SDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

A previously working lambda is now reporting an error

```
Property 'on' does not exist on type 'SdkStream<Readable| ReadableStream | Blob>
```

when I try to read data. The data is passed via the lambda event as a result of an S3 trigger

```
const data = await s3Client.send(new GetObjectCommand(sourceBucket));
data.Body.on('data', (data) => {
```

It looks as though the stream type has been changed to wrap with SdkStream?  AWS SDK version 3.197 to 3.279.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping the stream with sdkStreamMixin resolves the problem

```
const sdkStream = sdkStreamMixin(data.Body);
sdkStream.on('data', (data) => {
```

The AWS SDK now returning the wrapper rather than ReadableStream. It looks as though this is a fix for a change introduced in 3.127 (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/3807)?